# chromecast don't play HLS

Tags: chromecast

I try play hls(mpeg2ts) by chromecast custom receiver.
but chromecast don't play it.

```
1. reciever : https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Media-Player-Library-Sample
2. content : http://14.63.214.241/hlstest/hlstest.m3u8
```

chromecast loaded each ts file. (device tool->network)

don't display error log in console (device tool->console)

Any idea what might be wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed CORS (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player).
I did a quick test with your content-stream using CORS and using the Styled Media Receiver. It works on my Chromecast. I could see the soccer game :-) .